# Is this integral impossible to solve in any way?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

I have an integral I can not seem to solve. Any help would be much appreciated!

$\int e^x\sec\left(x\right)\:dx$

Comment: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5Ex+sec+x&x=0&y=0

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution to the integral:

$$\int e^x\sec x\,dx \;=\; (1-i) e^{(1+i) x} \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2},1;\frac{3}{2}-\frac{i}{2};-e^{2 i
   x}\right)+C$$

where $_2F_1\left(a,b\,;\,c\,;\,x\right)$ is the [Hypergeometric Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).